Select layers from a list of rasters based on specific patterns to create a new list of rasters
I have a list of rasters containing several layers. How can I select the layers based on certain patterns from this list of rasters to create a new list of rasters?
Here is a code to create the list of rasters (it's a reproducible example):
## Create the list of rasters
year <- seq(2021, 2040)
variables <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

raster_list <- list()

for (i in variables) {
  
  x <- terra::rast(nrows = 258, ncols = 600, 
                   xmin = -172, xmax = -22, ymin = 12, ymax = 76.5, 
                   resolution = 0.25, 
                   crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
  
  terra::values(x) <- 1:terra::ncell(x)
  test <- terra::rast(replicate(length(year), x))
  names(test) <- paste0("year_", year)
  raster_list[[i]] <- test
}

Here is the expected result from the list above:
$year_2021
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 258, 600, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -172, -22, 12, 76.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
names       :         A ,        B,         C,         D,         E,         F
min values  :         1,         1,         1,         1,         1,         1
max values  :    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800 

$year_2022
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 258, 600, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -172, -22, 12, 76.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
names       :         A ,        B,         C,         D,         E,         F
min values  :         1,         1,         1,         1,         1,         1
max values  :    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800,    154800

....

Update:
The list of rasters should not be modified.

Assuming you wanted to keep your raster_list object as-is and not restructure your SpatRaster objects in the desired dimensions from the beginning, you could also "swap" your dimensions (variables becoming layers and years becoming elements of your list) temporarily in order to be able to index your list as usual.
Wrapping this in a function is not necessary but maybe "guarantees" that your initial object is not modified (but has to be created in memory every time you're subsetting your list, and this might be quite time-consuming, depending on the size of your raster):
Basically, I'm using nested loops wrapping terra::subset() here:
r_mod <- function(x, idx) {
  
  rlst <- list()
  
  # assuming this is constant over variables
  years <- names(x[[1]])
  
  # "exchange" dimensions
  for (i in 1:length(years)) {
    
    rlst[[i]] <- lapply(x, terra::subset, years[i]) |> terra::rast()
  }
  
  # assign names
  names(rlst) <- years
  
  # index
  rlst[idx]
}

The result:
r_mod(raster_list, idx = c("year_2021", "year_2022"))
#> $year_2021
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 258, 600, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : -172, -22, 12, 76.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> names       :      A,      B,      C,      D,      E,      F 
#> min values  :      1,      1,      1,      1,      1,      1 
#> max values  : 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800 
#> 
#> $year_2022
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 258, 600, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : -172, -22, 12, 76.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> names       :      A,      B,      C,      D,      E,      F 
#> min values  :      1,      1,      1,      1,      1,      1 
#> max values  : 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800, 154800


Fixed my answer. Here is dimfalk's approach in a two-liner:
r <- lapply(1:length(year), \(y) rast(lapply(raster_list, \(x) x[[y]])))
names(r) <- paste0("year_", year)


Thank you very much for your response. I apologize, I may have formulated my issue incorrectly. In fact, the list of rasters should not be modified. My question is, how can I obtain the expected result from this list? I wanted to create a reproducible example.

I think your question was clear enough --- I did not read it well enough.
